# How to signal sole affiliation is honorary?

Tags: publications, mathematics, affiliation

(My field is pure mathematics)

**EDIT:** I asked this question as a form of thinking out loud. I've realised with the help of the commenters below that my inclinations were a bit stupid, but others in similar positions might find the discussion useful.

---

I have an honorary, 'visiting' affiliation with the university (in my city where I live) where I once had an academic position. I do not have a paid research position there, and the adjunct teaching positions I have had of late in the mathematics department there appear to have run out. I have library and building access, and am for most intents and purposes counted as staff, minus the actual job. I have continued steadily publishing papers in this position.

I am wondering what people would advise about listing my affiliation on papers. I have no complaints with the department, and they have been happy to renew my status, which is very nice. However, I would like to signal in some way that I am not in fact employed to do this research. The only way I can think of this is to stop listing myself as being 'at' the university in question, but this seems to me as ungrateful, or risking losing this affiliation.

I am also aware that the department gains from my producing research and listing it as having taken place there, without the actual full cost of employing me. This *may* lead to certain negative incentives, but this is pure supposition.

Comment: Do library privileges and building access come with any official title? At my university, you would be a "visiting scholar".  So if I were in your situation, I  could make my level of affiliation fairly clear by writing "Visiting Scholar, Mathematics Department, University of Michigan" in my publications. Could you do something analogous?

Comment: " I would like to signal in some way that I am not in fact employed to do this research."  Why?  It's the contents of the papers that matters, not the pay of the authors.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist one might like to signal that one is interested in jobs, or that the relative slowness of the release of that work is not due to laziness, or that one just doesn't have access to travel funds and so on. By the logic of your comment, one shouldn't need _author names_ on papers, since it's not even the identity of the authors that matters, only the contents.

Comment: @AndreasBlass presumably. Officially I'm a 'Visiting Fellow', but what on earth does that mean? Do people look at titles on papers? Translating what they mean between countries is subtle enough in the ordinary setting.

Comment: What I mean to say is: if I merely list a gmail address and no university, it stands out quite a bit. I'm really looking for any kind of advice here, or a solid argument why my vague inclination is a ridiculous idea and self-sabotaging, or even unethical. @AndreasBlass 's idea is good, as far as it goes.

Comment: @AndreasBlass writing "Visiting Scholar" with capital letters suggests that this is an official title granted by the institution. I would advise against writing that without express approval from the department chair, as doing it without authorization could be seen as a dishonest attempt at portraying yourself in a way that is unsanctioned and potentially disapproved of (for various legal or PR-related reasons) by the university administration.

Comment: David, in order to advise you about the pros and cons of listing or failing to list your affiliation in various ways, I think we need to better understand your motivation. What goal are you hoping to achieve by signaling that the affiliation is honorary? Your mention of negative incentives makes me suspect this is about signaling to the department your dissatisfaction with your unpaid status and hinting that they should upgrade it to a paid position, which (if true) sounds like a somewhat passive-aggressive, and in any case almost certainly ineffective, way of conveying that information.

Comment: Maybe you could ask your department's chair or equivalent boss how would they like to appear.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Announcing you are unemployed will actually make it harder to find a job.  Authors are listed to show who did the work.  Affiliations are listed to show where the authors are located, not to suggest the affiliated institution contributed to the work.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist if people need to locate me I  always list an email address :-) I didn't say I was looking for a job.

Comment: @DanRomik it is an official title, so no issues in that respect. I guess I'm wondering if there's a very real reason I _must_ list such an affiliation. I can think of some, but nothing hard and fast. And I don't mean of the kind "it will hurt your career" because I am at low risk of establishing an academic career, for reasons personal.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I can't think of a reason why you _must_ list your affiliation. However, I can think of several reasons why not listing your affiliation can hurt you in subtle ways (e.g. referees would be subconsciously or consciously biased when evaluating your affiliation-less papers), and on the other hand can't think of even a single way in which it might benefit you. So it all comes back to the question of motivation I commented on earlier: _what are you hoping to achieve with this sort of signal?_ It seems that either I'm missing something, or your question is based on some flawed premise.

Comment: @DanRomik I'm really not sure. Part of it is my slight antipathy towards the academic system as a whole. If I'm making research work (at some level) as an alt-academic, I'm not sure if I want to pretend I'm "at" a university, when the reality is more complicated. I really am conflicted about this, which is why I asked. In applying for early-career grants in Australia one is assessed on 'Research Opportunity and Performance Evidence', with the idea that 6 years out of my PhD less than half of that has been academic research employment (again, for personal reasons). Listing myself as being at a

Comment: ...university on my papers when not employed by the university seems to belie the fact I have not been paid to produce said papers for several years. Anyway, I'm just exposing my confusion to the world on this issue: I hope the collective wisdom here can come to a consensus as to what seems like the most sensible course of action.

Comment: The most sensible course of action is to list your affiliation on your papers in the normal way. The time you are spending worrying about this essentially meaningless issue would be better spent trying to actually improve your situation in more substantive ways. Just my two cents. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

An honourary appointment at my university comes with an email address, library privileges, internet access and a hot desk. In exchange, we advise our honourary staff that we are happy for them to list their affiliation with us in two wways: (1) "Honourary Research Fellow" or (2) "Research Fellow (Honourary)". They are, of course, under no obligation to do so.

In the journals I help edit, affiliations listed as honourary or adjunct or visiting carries no stigma. We treat it like any other affiliation. However, because there is a cap in the number of affiliations authors can list (we allow no more than three), an honourary affiliations are included in those counts.

Good luck!